# How to create/copy an EC2 sec group in Oregon using one in Virginia?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I would like to copy a security group from Virginia to Oregon but there is no such thing via the Amazon CLI.

Is there a way to create an EC2 security group as follows instead?

1. describe-db-security-groups --db-security-group-name *secgroup-virginia* >> sg.txt
2. create-db-security-group --db-security-group-name *secgroup-oregon* --region us-west-2 ***sg.txt***

Could I use the JSON output of the security group as input in the create command?

Comment: This script I use for migration of security groups between regions https://github.com/pedropregueiro/migrate-ec2-secgroups

Comment: Migration only makes sense if you use CIDR blocks only.  If you want to migrate rules that reference other security groups, those aren't universal.  If you're in EC2-Classic and the groups have the same name, that might work, but in a VPC, where you have to use the group-id, you'd need a way to map them.  There's no way to do this without scripting.